# Making `thumbs` thumb index display thumbs on both sides of the page (left and right) of book class

Tags: xetex, book-class, thumb-index

I am trying to create a version of printed document that is supposed to have symmetric left/right pages. For that I would like to change the appearance of thumb-index on the page which now is fully symmetric (given no printing is required). I would like to incur minimal changes to the original document/packages (e.g. not replacing `thumbs` package if not absolutely required).

I am using the following MWE and having trouble making the thumbs appear on both margins / sides of the page (or alternatively - only on one side). Is there a way to parametrize `thumbs` package in this way?

```
%!TEX TS -program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[paperwidth=190mm, paperheight=280mm, textwidth=170mm,  textheight=263mm, 
            top=14mm, bottom=22mm, inner=16.5mm, outer=16.5mm, headsep=3mm, headheight=6mm, footskip=12mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[width=12mm, height=9.5mm, distance=0.5mm, eventxtindent=2pt, oddtxtexdent=2pt, topthumbmargin=22mm, bottomthumbmargin=0pt]{thumbs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{A}
\addthumb{A}{A}{white}{black}
\lipsum[1-16]

\chapter*{B}
\addthumb{B}{B}{white}{black}
\lipsum

\chapter*{C}
\addthumb{C}{C}{white}{black}
\lipsum

\chapter*{D}
\addthumb{D}{D}{white}{black}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest altering the definition of `\cleardoublepage` to ignore the `\if@twoside` test.

This means you can switch between a one sided and two sided document without messing up pagination.

Then all you need to do is change you document class between

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
```

and

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
```

The redefined definition of `\cleardoublepage` becomes:

```
% ensure twoside always true when clearing a double page
% by removing \if@twoside test
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

In one sided mode, the thumbs will just appear on the right hand side of the page. In two sided mode, the thumbs will appear on alternating sides of the page. Only the `\documentclass` line of your file needs to be changed.